# Django Serializer - replacing a key with data from the database

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've got a Django model as such:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    document = models.TextField()
```

And I want to output JSON that looks like this (this is per result):

```
{(identifier): (document)}, etc
```

I am trying to figure out if there's a way to do this using the serializers.

So far I've got this:

```
class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    identifier = serializers.SerializerMethodField('getidentifier')
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('identifier', 'document')

    def getidentifier(self, obj):
        return obj.getidentifier
```

But I don't understand exactly what's going on or how to get/organize the values I want.

How do I take two values from the database, and turn them into a key:value pair, per result?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing something in the spirit of:

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize('json', Document.objects.all(), fields=('identifier','document'))
print data
```

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/)

The problem is, each field is going to be a key. If you want some fields to be the value, you'll need to make a custom method on your model to generate a dictionary as you want it and then simply turn it to JSON using `json.dumps()` or call the serializer on that method (that you can turn into a property with a decorator).

On a side note: Have you looked at/are using [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) ? It is a django app that has all you need for JSON APIs with serializers, deserializers etc.

Comment: I am using the REST framework, but didn't see any easy way to do what I wanted to do. Also, will this lead to identifier as a key, and document as a value? From what I'm reading of the documentation, that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you can override the `list()` method of your `MyDocumentListApiView`.

```
class MyDocumentListApiView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Document.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DocumentSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs): # override the 'list' method
        instance = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        page = self.paginate_queryset(instance)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_pagination_serializer(page)
        else:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, many=True)

        serializer_data = serializer.data # get the default serialized data 
        custom_data = [{x['identifier':x['document']} for x in serializer_data] # create your custom response data
        return Response(custom_data) # create response with this custom data
```